Updating search index fails due to following SQL error: SQLSTATE[HY001]: Memory allocation error
This error: SQLSTATE[HY001]: Memory allocation error: 1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size is causing the Updating Search Indexes job to fail. The section that is causing this failure is a Channel called walks. We have also seen this issue affect the admin/entries/walks page in the Control Panel. When accessing admin/entries/walks, no entries are displayed and an error message reading "A server error has occurred." appears in the bottom left hand corner of the page. This message also appears when attempting to export the entries.
Walks entries have a read-only plain text field that uses the Incognito Field plugin and is of type Incognito Field rendered in Read-only mode. This field contains data in .geojson format and can be quite large. Is there a way to exclude this field from the query performed by this job/when the entries page is accessed in the Control Panel? The SQL being executed that causes the failure is as follows:
SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`canonicalId`, `elements`.`fieldLayoutId`, `elements`.`uid`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateLastMerged`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `siteSettingsId`, `elements_sites`.`siteId`, `elements_sites`.`title`, `elements_sites`.`slug`, `elements_sites`.`uri`, `elements_sites`.`content`, `elements_sites`.`enabled` AS `enabledForSite`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`fieldId`, `entries`.`primaryOwnerId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`, `elements`.`draftId`, `drafts`.`creatorId` AS `draftCreatorId`, `drafts`.`provisional` AS `isProvisionalDraft`, `drafts`.`name` AS `draftName`, `drafts`.`notes` AS `draftNotes` FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `siteSettingsId` FROM `elements` `elements` INNER JOIN `entries` `entries` ON `entries`.`id` = `elements`.`id` INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id` LEFT JOIN `drafts` `drafts` ON `drafts`.`id` = `elements`.`draftId` WHERE (`entries`.`sectionId`=4) AND (`elements`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (`elements`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`canonicalId` IS NULL) AND ((`elements`.`draftId` IS NULL) OR (`drafts`.`provisional`=FALSE)) AND ((`elements`.`draftId` IS NULL) OR (NOT (`elements`.`canonicalId` IS NULL)) OR (`drafts`.`saved`=TRUE)) AND (`elements`.`revisionId` IS NULL) ORDER BY `postDate` IS NULL DESC, `postDate` DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 200) `subquery` INNER JOIN `elements` `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId` INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`id` = `subquery`.`siteSettingsId` INNER JOIN `entries` `entries` ON `entries`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId` LEFT JOIN `drafts` `drafts` ON `drafts`.`id` = `elements`.`draftId` ORDER BY `postDate` IS NULL DESC, `postDate` DESC;

I don’t know what version of Craft or MySQL you’re on, but this could either be a MySQL bug, a MySQL configuration issue, an Incognito plugin bug, or a Craft bug.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67266529
I’d start by ensuring you’re running the latest versions of each to rule out issues that have already been fixed.
